# Выбор каталога установки venv в Python 3.7.4 на Windows

Tags: python, windows-10

Как выбрать каталог для установки виртуального окружения в Windows? Стандартное расположение находится в `C:\Users\"Имя пользователя"\` то-есть папка с виртуальным окружением создаётся именно там следующим кодом:

```py
python -m venv "Имя окружения"
```

Каким образом создать окружение в заранее созданной папке, например, в папке Документы?

Comment: Это не "Имя окружения", а путь к папке, в которой окружение будет создано

Answer (score 0):

Задать абсолютный путь:

```
python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
```

Comment: Ну или относительный — `path\to\myenv`, лишь бы правильный был.

Answer (score 0):

Уж точно не помню, есть ли в инсталяторе Python среды опция выбора пути установки, но если просто переместить папку с файлами (или сами файлы переместить в другую директорию), то venv на это капризничать не будет. Будет просто работать, как ни в чём не бывало, из текущей директории.